# Web Api to extract information from website

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, api

I need kind of service that extracts title from web page and returns in from of json. I would not like to parse web page or waste any unnecessary CPU cycles.
ie call should be something like this:

```
curl http://api.someservice.com/fetch?url=google.com&element=title&out=json
```

Response from api would be:

```
{
    response: {
        title: "Google"
        source: "google.com"
    }
    status: "success"

}
```

Any hint would be highly appreciated

Comment: This really isn't a programming question, is it?

Comment: Have you looked into [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/)?

Comment: Hint: Hire a programmer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have a look at [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) - it's a general-purpose service from Yahoo! that can do this kind of scraping really easily. Try this:

```
select * from html where url="google.com" and xpath='//title'
```

[Test it here.](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20%2a%20from%20html%20where%20url=%22google.com%22%20and%20xpath=%27//title%27)

Comment: exactly what I'm looking for ... and even more!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that Yahoo!'s [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) is probably pretty close to what you're looking for.

(In fact I think that a concise description of what YQL is would be, "a web API to extract information from a website" :-)